# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_151_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 2100)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using the Keras API to write a code that can predict using the learned .h5 file.

The learning model is as follows

```
#Libraries
import keras
from keras import backend as k
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

#Create 2 numpy lists that will hold both our sample data and raw data
train_labels = []
train_samples = []

#declare array to hold training data as well as label
train_samples_temp_a = []
train_samples_temp_b = []

#Generate data
for i in range(1000):
    #YOUNGER PEOPLE
    random_younger_a = randint(13,64)
    random_younger_b = randint(13,64)
    train_samples_temp_a.append(random_younger_a)
    train_samples_temp_b.append(random_younger_b)
    train_labels.append(0)
    #OLDER PEOPLE
    random_older_a = randint(65,100)
    random_older_b = randint(65,100)
    train_samples_temp_a.append(random_older_a)
    train_samples_temp_b.append(random_older_b)
    train_labels.append(1)

for i in range(50):
    #YOUNGER PEOPLE
    random_younger_a = randint(13,64)
    random_younger_b = randint(13,64)
    train_samples_temp_a.append(random_younger_a)
    train_samples_temp_b.append(random_younger_b)
    train_labels.append(1)
    #OLDER PEOPLE
    random_older_a = randint(65,100)
    random_older_b = randint(65,100)
    train_samples_temp_a.append(random_older_a)
    train_samples_temp_b.append(random_older_b)
    train_labels.append(0)

#Array of Two Arrays 
train_samples.append(train_samples_temp_a)
train_samples.append(train_samples_temp_b)

#Convert both train_label and train_sample list into a numpy array
train_samples = np.array(train_samples)
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

#Scale down train_samples to numbers between 0 and 1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_train_samples=scaler.fit_transform((train_samples))

#Sequential Model
model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, input_shape=(2,2100), activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

#Compile Model
model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics= ['accuracy'])

#Train Model
model.fit(scaled_train_samples, train_labels, validation_split = 0.20, 
batch_size=10, epochs=20, shuffle=True, verbose=2)
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

I used the Transpose function to reshape scaled_train_samples from a 2 by 2100 matrix into a 2100 by 2 matrix. Thanks guys for your contributions.

```
#Transpose
scaled_train_samples = scaled_train_samples.transpose()
```

However, running the line of code below gives the accuracy of the model. And currently, I am getting an accuracy of 51.52%, is there anything I can do to improve the accuracy of this model?

```
#Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(scaled_train_samples, train_labels)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input_shape=(2100,)`

The input shape should not contain the batch size.

Comment: hey, I tried input_shape=(2100,) and also removed Flatten() function as well as the batch_size but i still get similar error message: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 2 input samples and 2100 target samples.

Comment: @IfeanyiNdukwe That's not a similar error, its completely different, means your features and targets have different number of samples, and they should be the same.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, I still do not know how to get the above code to run. Are you able to get it to run?

Comment: You must shape your input and output data properly. If you have 2100 examples, it must be the first dimension in both input and output. If, on the other hand, you have 2 samples, 2 must be the first dimension. If, yet another case, none of these values are samples, then you need to have an additional first dimension for the number of samples, but only you know what your data is and what it means to organize it properly.

Comment: @Daniel Möller, thats is exactly why I posted the code. In the code, 'train_samples' holds the sample data while 'train_labels' holds the labels. every other line runs well its only the last line of code that generates the error message. I want to get it to run. Thanks.